# I am learning tensorflow2 in python and i am wondering what sets the ndim?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, python-3.6

```
def build_model(layers):
    model = Sequential()

    # By setting return_sequences to True we are able to stack another LSTM layer
    model.add(LSTM(layers[0], input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True))

    model.add(LSTM(layers[0], input_shape=(1, 2),
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
    print("Compile Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

Then when i try to run model.fit after building it. That is when the error gets thrown. Here is a snippet of the code of the model getting built and the model.fit function.

```
window = 20
print("X_train", X_train.shape)
print("y_train", y_train.shape)
print("X_test", X_test.shape)
print("y_test", y_test.shape)

model = build_model([1374, window, 100, 1])

model.fit(X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=3,
    epochs=5,
    validation_split=0.1,
    verbose=0).
```

Here is the error message. ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatable with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. What is the ndim? What does its value adjust on the model? How do I understand what ndim I set.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2).
```

Here is the print out of the shapes.

```
X_train (1032, 2)
y_train (1032, 2)
X_test (344, 2)
y_test (344, 2)
```

Comment: `LSTM layer is a recurrent layer, hence it expects a 3-dimensional input (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. Include the `X_train` shape in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @yudhiesh, LSTM expects input shape 3D Tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`
I could reproduce your issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-160c5e8d5d9a> in <module>()
      2 inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
      3 lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
----> 4 output = lstm(inputs)
      5 print(output.shape)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    217                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    218                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 219                          str(tuple(shape)))
    220     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    221       ndim = x.shape.rank

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)
```

**Working sample code**

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output:**

```
(32, 4)
```